# SQL database data into an array

Tags: sqlite, pascal, lazarus

I currently have a program which connects to a database and displays the data on a DBGrid, however I need to extract this data so I can use it in another algorithm.

When I use the command: select scores from quiz

It shows the values on the screen. (23,55,64)

How do I get these values into an array so that

```
[0]=23
[1]=55
[2]=64
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your existing code.

Comment: You are thinking about the problem in the wrong way.  The TDBGrid is just a gui object for displaying the data from the database.  What you should be working with is the TDataSet-descendant object that you are using to populate the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use TList (which is an array wrapper object). Below is an excerpt from some code that I use. TSomeRect is a record to store the field data of each row in.

```
function CreateQuery(pConnection: Tsqlconnection; pTransaction: TSQLTransaction): TSQLQuery;
begin
  result := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  result.Database := pConnection;
  result.Transaction := pTransaction
end;
var
 connect: TSQLite3Connection;
 SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
 transact: TSQLTransaction;
 Query        : TSQLQuery;

 lst :TList<TSomeRect>;
  rec :TSomeRect;
begin

 lst :=TList<TSomeRect>.create;
 connect:=TSQLite3Connection.create(nil);

 connect.LoginPrompt := False;
 connect.DatabaseName := 'c:\path\to\database.sqlite';
 connect.KeepConnection := False;
 transact:=TSQLTransaction.create(nil);
 transact.action:=caNone;
 transact.database:=connect;
 connect.Transaction:=transact;

 Query := CreateQuery(Connect, Transact);
 Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from table';
 Connect.Open;
 Query.Open;
 while not Query.Eof do
  begin
     rec.field1:= Query.FieldByName('field1').AsInteger; 
     rec.field2:= Query.FieldByName('field2').Asstring; 
     lst.add(rec);
     Query.Next;
  end;
 Query.Close;
 Connect.Close;
 Query.Free;
 Transact.Free;
 Connect.Free;
```